# CURL command exiting with exit code 56 with error Failure when receiving data from peer

Tags: curl

I am trying to run this curl command in a unix host

```
curl -v -s -X POST -m 3600 -H "minutes: 10" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" "endpoint" -w "%{http_code}"
```

Basically the curl command hits an api endpoint that sleeps for the time given in the minutes header and then returns a response.

When I am running the curl command in a unix host, it returns a `000` response with `exit code 56` and error Failure when receiving data from peer after 5 minutes.

The curl command works fine when I am running it from my local machine giving a `200` response. How to resolve this??